# Event handlers can only be bound to HttpApplication events during IHttpModule initialization shows up at random

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am working on an existing web forms app and originally hosted it in IIS but could not getting debugging to work.. So now I am using IIS Express but I get this error that pops up seemingly randomly without me doing anything!

.. Any idea what this could be coming from ? Or what to look into ?

Comment: Where is this showing up - in the event log, in the debugger, or elsewhere?  Can you provide the stack trace of the error?

Comment: In the debugger.. randomly.. Only happens when using IIS express... not IIS.. though I cannot debug using IIS so I must use IIS express and attempt to debug before the random error shows up.. its all very strange and I gave up trying to fix it but if anyone ever has any idea what is going on that would be good to know